# Is it possible to select different rows each time without knowing any fields to sort?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-cursor

I have a query, let's say `X_QUERY`, this query could be anything (we don't know any field) and could have a hundred million of rows. I need to divide the result in up to 16 chunks, so each chunk has **completely different** rows of `X_QUERY`. We could assume there are no updates in any table during the process.

I have solved the same problem in oracle using `ROWID` as `order by` clause, so I have tried using `CTID` in Postgres, but did not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (X_QUERY) as origin ORDER BY ctid -- <-- ctid does not exist here
limit 6250000 offset 0; -- <-- next offsets should be 6250000, 12500000 etc.
```

Ideally, I would like to avoid the added cost of `order by`, but I did not find any other way (at least using Oracle).

So, Is there a way to avoid some kind of order?
If not, is there a way to select different rows each time not knowing any field to order by?

Comment: Pagination in postgresql: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand it, those approaches do not solve the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the rare cases I would look to an SQL **cursor**. [The manual on `DECLARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html):

> `DECLARE` allows a user to create cursors, which can be used to retrieve a small number of rows at a time out of a larger query.

It does not care about the underlying sort order and returns rows in the sequence the query produced it.

Use [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) to get the next set of rows.

Example:

```sql
BEGIN;
DECLARE x_cursor CURSOR FOR <X_QUERY>;  -- your query string here

FETCH 6250000 FROM x_cursor;
FETCH 6250000 FROM x_cursor;
FETCH 6250000 FROM x_cursor;
-- repeat until no more rows;

-- CLOSE x_cursor;  -- optional
COMMIT;
-- or ROLLBACK;  -- does not make a difference in this case
```

Must all be done within a transaction unless you declare the corsor `WITH HOLD`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html):

> Unless `WITH HOLD` is specified, the cursor created by this command
> can only be used within the current transaction. Thus, `DECLARE`
> without `WITH HOLD` is useless outside a transaction block: the cursor
> would survive only to the completion of the statement. Therefore
> PostgreSQL reports an error if such a command is used outside a
> transaction block. Use `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`) to define
> a transaction block.

If you have your query as *string*, you might use dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function or `DO` statement to create an SQL cursor (`WITH HOLD`?) dynamically, or use a [PL/pgSQL cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) to begin with (related, but separate implementation).

---

> I have tried using CTID in postgres, but did not work.

That's because `ctid` is a system column identifying the physical location of a tuple. It's not included in the result of a query unless listed in the `SELECT` list explicitly. So it's typically not in the result of a given query, and it's not necessarily unique in that derived table. Hence, the `ctid` can be used to walk through a table without concurrent writes, but it's no good for your purpose.
More gory details:

- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007/3684)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a window function to the X_QUERY called row_number().

Comment: The only possible way I see is to use row_number() over(), and that doesn't guarantee the same chunk every time we run the same query, so the chunks couldn't be guarantee different from each other.

Comment: Hmm. That information was missing in your initial post.

So, the rows of X_QUERY are not unique?